# When I Add <DIV> Bottom Scroll Bar Appears, Even Though It Is Not Greater Than The Page Width

Tags: html, css

I have searched for this with no answer.  My page loads up perfectly when I load the header, navigation and then center image...all 3 different divs.  However I have more I need to add and the div tags change the size of the page even though the css I'm using isn't larger than the page.  I have no idea what is happening.

Here's the code page where everything is fine:

http://www.thehdmgroup.com/midwaymissionary/test.php

When I add the below div tag with the below css I get a bottom scrollbar on the page and I don't know why.  Can someone please explain it to me?

```
#middleTextBox1 {
    position: absolute; 
    top:507px; 
    left:172px; 
    width:180px; 
    height:180px; 
    background-color:#411b42; 
    border: 1px 
    solid #434343; 
    padding:10px; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    font-size: 10px; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

<div id="middleTextBox1">
  <h3 align="center">Mission:</h3>
  Words
</div>
```

I really have no idea why this is happening, could someone please help me out?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: in which browser/computer that you test your webpage?

Answer (score 2):

Working fine on my computer.

Your browser client area may be smaller than 507+180+10+10+1+1 px (top + height + paddingTop + paddingBottom + borderTop + borderBottom) or 172+180+10+10+1+1 (horizontally).

**EDIT**

Your center image is 1025px wide.  The client area in your browser window is less than that.  You can

- Resize the window
- Buy a new monitor
- Design your site so overflow is OK
- Forcibly turn off overflow with `overflow-x:hidden`

Comment: I think there is a tongue in your cheek @Steve.

Answer (score 0):

what browser are you running this on? including the browser version? because i have ran it under Firefox 3.x and i don't see any problems.